How to reliably record input texts on each keystroke?
Here is a simple web page which stores unique input texts as Map keys. This is triggered the keyup event on the text input field. In case a particular text already exists in the Map, a message "repeat" is displayed in the label with id = 'old'. This works as expected when I type slowly but it usually displays "repeat" when I type quickly, even for first time texts. How can I fix this?


class KeyupClass {
  newlabel = document.getElementById('new');

  textmap = new Map();

  oldlabel = document.getElementById('old');

  update = (event) => {
    this.newlabel.innerHTML = `new text ${event.target.value}`;
    if (this.textmap.has(event.target.value)) this.oldlabel.innerHTML = 'repeat';
    else {
      this.textmap.set(event.target.value, this.oldlabel.innerHTML);
      this.oldlabel.innerHTML = `previous text ${event.target.value}`;
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    document.getElementById('textinput').addEventListener('keyup', this.update);
  }
}
new KeyupClass();
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>keyup event test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: grid">
    <label>editing input updates old and new labels on each keystroke</label>
    <input type="text" id="textinput" placeholder="add text here" />
    <label id="old">old text</label>
    <label id="new">new text</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Aside: <label> isn't an appropriate tag for this. That should be the label associated with an input element. Use <div>.

keyup is probably not the best event to use. It's triggered when you press keys that don't change the value, such as shift keys, and not triggered when you use menu items like Cut and Paste. input may be better.

This seems like an XY Problem. Besides what Barmar said, what is that you're building? Took me some time to reproduce the issue BTW... Why would you want to use Map() for that thing? What's the point? The test case you provided is hard to understand in terms of - what is that you're really trying to accomplish?!

@Barmar I agree the use of <label> and this code was quick and dirty hack - but I was tired and needed sleep. I tested the input event, which I had never heard of, and that works much better, thanks!

@RokoC.Buljan I am trying to build a nested structure editor. I want user input to immediately update an internal structure (for example - a Map) by simply changing the input element contents. Here is my severely broken and incomplete prototype -https://shanemcandrewai.github.io/

Thank you for trying to explain, but, I still don't understand. And after opening the demo git page I have no clue what I'm looking at... what should that tool do, and where is the input text gone... :/

@RokoC.Buljan After opening the git page, put the cursor in one of the key fields and press a bunch of random keys and fast possible. The app is supposed to switch the background colour of the input field to red only if it detects a duplicate key. I think the solution is probably to use input event instead of keyup event. I have reproduced the bug in this screenshot https://paste.pics/7052ec581d2e37c50b82c56ce18a69e1

It seems like you'll get frequent duplicates while editing. E.g. if you type abc and then delete the c, the remaining ab will be a duplicate of what you had typed before the c.

@Barmar simply replacing keyup with the input event solved the bug, see updated https://shanemcandrewai.github.io/

@user2309803 are you sure that just "input" resolved the bug? Try to use i.e: Backspace (fast), and there's the bug again. Sorry, for now I'm out of this question, I still don't understand what you're building, why you use map() and what is that app for and supposed to solve and what should be its output :\ That might be just me. Hope you'll find an answer soon! And happy coding
